# Microsoft Graph throttling Excel updates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a Node.js app which connects to the Microsoft Graph API.

Often times, I get back a `429` status code, which is described as "Too Many Requests" in the [error documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors).

Sometimes the message returned is:

> TooManyRequests. Client application has been throttled and should not attempt to repeat the request until an amount of time has elapsed.

Other times, it returns:

> "TooManyRequests.  The server is busy. Please try again later.".

Unfortunately, it is not returning a `Retry-After` field in the headers, even though their [best practices](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling) claims that it should do so.

This is entirely in development, and I have not been hitting the service much, as it has all been during debugging.  I realize Microsoft is often changing how this works.  I just find it difficult to develop an app around a service which does not even provide a `Retry-After` field, and seems to have a lot of problems (I am using the `v1.0` endpoint).

When I wait 5 minutes (as I have seen recommended), the service still errors out.  Here is an example return response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "TooManyRequests",
        "message": "The server is busy. Please try again later.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d963bb00-6bdf-4d6b-87f9-973ef00de211",
            "date": "2017-08-31T23:09:32"
        }
    }
}
```

Could this relate at all to the operation being carried out?

I am updating a range from `A2:L3533`. They are all text values.  I am wondering if this could impact the throttling. I have not found any guidance regarding using "smaller" operation sets.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to diagnose exactly what is going on. That said, you're Range here is *enormous* and almost certainly will result in issues.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel#large-range):

> Large Range implies a Range of a size that is too large for a single API call. Many factors such as number of cells, values, numberFormat, and formulas contained in the range can make the response so large that it becomes unsuitable for API interaction. The API makes a best attempt to return or write to the requested data. However, the large size involved might result in an API error condition because of the large resource utilization.
>
> To avoid this, we recommend that you read or write for large Range in multiple smaller range sizes.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  Even as I make the request small, to change 1 cell, I am still getting the same message, and I have not hit the servers in 12+ hours.  In the Graph Explorer, I do a Patch to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/MyFile.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/MySheetName/range(address='a2:a2') with the following JSON body "{
  "values": [
        [
            "12"
        ]
    ]

}" It returns " TooManyRequests" in a Status Code 429.

Comment: I still get the 429 status code when I try to update one cell at a time.   Even that is being throttled.  It would be nice to have some transparency, to understand why the system is doing it.

Comment: Also, even though they both respond with a status code 429, the message for "The server is busy. Please try again later."  does not seem like it should be bundled in with the 429 status code for throttling.  If the message is to be believed, this system is extremely busy.

Comment: It sounds like something else is going on here. It certainly shouldn't throttle after a single call. I would recommend opening a ticket with support so someone can investigate what is going on in your tenant. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  This is not even happening from code, this is from the Graph Explorer.

Comment: The support people only work with admin's, of which I am not.