# How to Change Microsoft Graph requests from throttling Excel requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am calling the Microsoft Graph REST API from Node.js (JavaScript).  I receive the result of GET operations for a single cell which is empty as returned with a status code 429 "TooManyRequests - The server is busy. Please try again later." error.  Another SO question [ [Microsoft Graph throttling Excel updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991320/microsoft-graph-throttling-excel-updates) ] has answers that point to MS documentation about making smaller requests.  Unfortunately, the suggestions are rather vague.

**My question is does the size of the file in OneDrive have an impact on throttling?**  The file I am attempting to update is over 4 MB in size.  However, the updates (PATCH) that I have attempted are only 251 bytes (12 cells) and I continue to get the error.  Even a GET for a single cell receives this.  This happened after 72 hours of inactivity.  I am using a business account, and unfortunately MS support will not help, as they will only speak to Admins.

Assuming this is an unrelated issue, as I do have about 3500 rows (of about 12 columns) to update, **what is the best "chunk size" to update them in?  Is 50 ok?  Is 100 ok?**  Thank You!

NOTE: This same throttling happens in the Graph Explorer, not just via code.  Also, **there is no Retry-After field returned in the Response Headers**.

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question, your Office tenant appears to have an issue. The only way to confirm and correct this is through a support ticket. This isn't something the SO community can help resolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Graph throttling Excel updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991320/microsoft-graph-throttling-excel-updates)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I am unable to get support from Microsoft, as I mentioned in this post and in the previous question.

Comment: So there is no answer to specifics on how to handle throttling?  When there are 3500 rows to update, what is an appropriate number to choose to do at a time?  I have been able to do all the rows at once through the Graph Explorer in the past.  Then it immediately won't update.  What is an appropriate value to start at?  There are questions above which have not been answered.